# Changing Company Information in setup does not carry over to already activated journey emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, setup

I recently updated the Company Information section in each of my business units as our company moved to a new address.

However, I have just noticed that for any existing emails in active journeys, the email is still showing our old address. I have tested for new emails and the address is correct. Additionally if I Preview and Test the journey emails they also show the correct address.

Is this a case of needing to manually go into the every email and force it to update (the same way I would have to do for a template update)? Is there a way to force all emails to use the new address?

Comment: Yes, you will need to apply these changes as the content is cached in the journey. The easiest way to do this is to go to Email Studio > Interactions > Messages > Journey Builder Sends. Then find the active version of your journey in the sub folder and pause, publish and then restart all of the triggers in the folder. The other alternative is to go into the journey and re-save each email activity (much more tedious).

Comment: Thanks, good to know.